# Newbie addEventListener style CSS change all <li>

Tags: javascript, css

This is so basic. I'm trying to model various addEventListener scenarios to simply change css style elements.

Here is the html

```
<ul>
  <li>bullet 1</li>
  <li>bullet 2</li>
</ul>
```

here is the javascript

```
const giraffe = document.querySelector("li");

giraffe.addEventListener("click", myFunc);

function myFunc(){
   giraffe.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
}
```

I'm trying to understand the behavior.

- Why does this only work when you click on the first li (nothing happens when you click the second)
- Why don't all the lis change color when you click on one li

Total newbie. I just about understand arrow functions and can read anonymous functions but I find it easier to follow if you can spell out any extra functions

Comment: `querySelector()` returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.
`querySelectorAll()` returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

Answer (score 0):

This is because that the query selector only selects the first occurence that fits the criteria. Consider adding IDs on the HTML elements and select them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have more than one of the similar elements, `querySelector` is only applied to the first element always. It's also the reason why your style only works on `giraffe` which is the first element.

If you want your click event and style to be applied to all similar elements, you should use `querySelectorAll` and a loop `forEach` to change element by element.

```js
const giraffes = document.querySelectorAll("li");

giraffes.forEach(giraffe => giraffe.addEventListener("click", myFunc));

function myFunc(){
   giraffes.forEach(giraffe => giraffe.style.backgroundColor = "#f00");
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>bullet 1</li>
  <li>bullet 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, I have to go to work now so I will sift and implement when I get back home.

Answer (score 0):

1. It works on only the first one because that is the behavior of `document.querySelector` it returns the first element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If you want it to affect all the `li` elements you should consider using `document.querySelectorAll`
2. That's because the click event is attached to just the first li element and this code: `giraffe.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";` is changing the background color of just that element.

You can improve your code using the below snippet.

```
 const lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
    lis.forEach(li => {
        li.addEventListener('click', () => {
            li.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
        })
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Eric! 
In this example, the forEach, which I have not used before opens up a {} which attaches the addEventListener to every li, then an anonymous arrow function gets further attached to the chain. I tried to move the function out of the forEach to be a stand alone function and it broke. So in order to run this, it is necessary to use the arrow or at least anonymous function approach, otherwise it cannot get chained on?

I aim to teach others in my lab as progress with the javascript journey and, these kinds of simple things sometimes require a lot of scaffolding. Thank you again!